# Node.js Child Processes failing GitHub ssh authentication

Tags: node.js, git, github

### Goal

Hello, I am creating a Node.js application to update my code when a push is made automatically.

### Problem

Everything works in it, except, the actual git pull. The repo is private and needs to use ssh, however when I use the same command in terminal it works. I have keychaining on so it doesn't ask for my passphrase. Any ideas and how to fix this?

### Relevant code

```
const exec = require("child_process").exec;

exec('cd ' + repo + ' && git pull origin deployment', (egitpull,stdoutgitpull,stderrgitpull)=>{
  if(egitpull) return console.error(`git pull exec error:${egitpull}`)
  console.log(`git pull stdout: ${stdoutgitpull}`);
  console.log(`git pull stderr: ${stderrgitpull}`);
```

#### Command run:

```
cd /mp/ && git pull origin deployment
```

#### Out of child process vrs. in child process

[image]

## Edit:

Removing the passphrase from the key entirely does seem to solve the issue, but I would much prefer having it in there for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an ssh-agent for your ssh keys, try forwarding the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID` env variables to the child process, like this:

```
exec('cd ' + repo + ' && git pull origin deployment',
        {
            env: {
                SSH_AUTH_SOCK: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
                SSH_AGENT_PID: process.env.SSH_AGENT_PID
            }
        },
        (egitpull,stdoutgitpull,stderrgitpull) => {
            // ...
        });
```